# HDFS: How to make writing atomic?

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

I have somewhat (weird) use case where writing to a HDFS file (side HDFS file) from multiple mappers is desired. But I am not sure whether that is allowed without breaking the integrity of the file. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS itself has no offering for such a need. Only one active writer is supported over a file at a single point.

You could use a distributed locking mechanism in your writer, appending and closing at every write instance (slow but achieves what you want), or write individually and merge up at end (faster in a distributed environment).